# Access to files from extension return sometimes NS_ERROR_FILE_IS_LOCKED

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Our extension (Addon SDK) looking for new files in folder `C:\scan` and send it to server. Every second extension look for  latest file creation time and defined it as latest.(compare new file creation time and  file creation time 1 sec ago.) 
Files put to `C:\scan` from scanner Brother 7050 on Windows 7.

But sometimes into console.error  we see:

```
Exception 
message: "Component returned failure code: 0x8052000e (NS_ERROR_FILE_IS_LOCKED)
[nsIFileInputStream.init]",
result: 2152857614,
name: "NS_ERROR_FILE_IS_LOCKED"
```

I think Brother 7050 application have no time to unlock file before our extension can start to read it.

Q: How we can read latest file in folder true way without read file lock error?

```
/*
adr- folder path
array2 - array for search
mode - search or not search in array2 (0-1)
*/
function getfilelist(adr,array2, mode)
{
     filelist2=[];
     filelist2[0]="";
     filelist2[1]=0;
     var file = new FileUtils.File(adr);       
        var enumerator = file.directoryEntries;        
        while (enumerator.hasMoreElements())
        {
             inner = enumerator.getNext().QueryInterface(Ci.nsIFile);
            if (inner.isFile())
            {                
                    namearray=inner.leafName.split(".");
                    r=namearray[namearray.length-1];
                    if (r=="jpg" || r=="jpeg")
                    {      
                        if (mode==0)
                        {
                            if (inner.lastModifiedTime>filelist2[1])
                            {
                            filelist2[0]=inner.leafName;
                            filelist2[1]=inner.lastModifiedTime;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (mode==1)
                        {
                            if (inner.lastModifiedTime>array2[1] && inner.isReadable()==true)
                                return inner.leafName;
                        }                        
                    }
            }            
        }
        if (mode==0)
        {
            return filelist2;
        }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have a hard time understanding what is actually your question. I gather that you're checking a directory (where you place some scans) for new and modified images periodically (once each second). File modification is checked for by comparing the file dates. Then, when trying to read new/modified files, you sometimes encounter `NS_ERROR_FILE_IS_LOCKED` exceptions. *Am I right so far?* **Now what is your question exactly? And also: what is your code?**

Comment: Ya man if you can help explain a bit better im hoping to swoop in and get the help points before nmaier :P

Comment: Nmailer, you are genius to decode my hieroglyphs)  question have been update.

Comment: @Alexufo: It is generally a good idea to cite the code throwing the exception rather than some other code. The code above doesn't use `nsIFileInputStream`, the exception is apparently being thrown when the caller of this function attempt to read the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you see `NS_ERROR_FILE_IS_LOCKED` is most likely that the file is still being written and you are trying to access it too early. However, it is also possible that some other software immediately locks the file to check it, e.g. [your anti-virus](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/09/07/10347136.aspx).

Either way, there is no way to ignore the lock. Even if you could, you might get an incomplete file as a result. What you *should* do is noting that exception and remembering that you should try to read that file on next run. Something along these lines:

```
var {Cr} = require("chrome");

var unaccessible = null;
setInterval(checknewfiles, 1000);

function checknewfiles()
{
  var files = getfilelist(...);
  if (unaccessible)
  {
    // Add any files that we failed to read before to the end of the list
    files.push.apply(files, unaccessible);
    unaccessible = null;
  }
  for (var file of files)
  {
    try
    {
      readfile(file);
    }
    except(e if e.result == Cr.NS_ERROR_FILE_IS_LOCKED)
    {
      if (!unaccessible)
        unaccessible = [];
      unaccessible.push(file);
    }
  }
}
```

For reference:

- [Components.results](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Components.results)
- [Chrome authority](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Chrome_Authority)
- [Conditional `catch` clauses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#Conditional_catch_clauses)
- [`for..of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: Wladimir, you should change name to Wladimir Talant. Thanks for your opinion. Yes, `brother control center` looks like lock file. Avast  seems make additional locking. Without him windows WIA seems works fine without locking. We will  catch (c.c.catch :- )) error) 
What do you think about listeting new files from event of file system? Maybe like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465%28VS.85%29.aspx
of course in this way we should use js-ctypes..